# All price doesn't sum up the prices instead it puts the prices next to each other

Tags: javascript, input, numbers, sum

I want to sum up some prices and put them in All price input, but the function doesn't sum the numbers, it puts the numbers next to each other. Is there any code that changes the string to the number?

```
 <html>

<label class="fa">ext modeling price</label>
<input type="number"  class="form-control" onchange="allPrc();" id="model-
ext-price" placeholder= "0" ></input>
<br>
<label class="fa">int modeling price</label>
<input type="number"  class="form-control" onchange="allPrc();" id="model-
int-price" placeholder= "0" ></input>   
<hr class="hrline">

<label class="fa"> ext renderign price</label>
<input type="number"  class="form-control" onchange="allPrc();" id="render-
ext-price" placeholder= "0" ></input>
<br>
<label class="fa">int rendering price  </label>
<input type="number"  class="form-control" onchange="allPrc();" id="render-
int-price" placeholder= "0" y></input>
<hr class="hrline">
<label class="fa">pproduction price   </label>
<input type="number"  class="form-control" onchange="allPrc();"  
id="pproduction-price" placeholder= "0" y></input>
<hr class="hrline">
<label class="fa"> All price </label>
<input type="number"  class="form-control"  id="All-price" placeholder= "0" 
readonly></input>
  </html> 


      <script>

    document.getElementById ('model-ext-price').onchange = function() {allPrc();};
    document.getElementById ('model-int-price').onchange = function() {allPrc();};
    document.getElementById ('render-ext-price').onchange = function() {allPrc();};
    document.getElementById ('render-int-price').onchange = function() {allPrc();};
    document.getElementById ('pproduction-price').onchange = function() {allPrc();};





var  allPrc = function () { 
 var Totalextmdl = document.getElementById ('model-ext-price').value,
    Totalintmdl = document.getElementById ('model-int-price').value,
    Totalextrndr = document.getElementById ('render-ext-price').value,
    Totalintrndr = document.getElementById ('render-int-price').value,
    Totalpp = document.getElementById ('pproduction-price').value,
    TotalPrc = 0;

 document.getElementById('All-price').value = TotalPrc;

    var TotalPrc = Totalextmdl + Totalintmdl + Totalextrndr + Totalintrndr + 
 Totalpp;

    document.getElementById('All-price').value = (TotalPrc>0 && 
   TotalPrc!=='NaN')?TotalPrc:0;

};

     </script>
```

Comment: It because JS believe that this is a string, so the plus sign just basically concat strings. You need to parse into floats your numbers : ```parseFloat(Totalextmdl = document.getElementById ('model-ext-price').value)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.value` returns a *string*. You want numbers. One easy way to convert your field values is to use a unary `+` when you first fetch them, like this:

```
var Totalextmdl = +document.getElementById('model-ext-price').value,
    Totalintmdl = +document.getElementById('model-int-price').value,
    Totalextrndr = +document.getElementById('render-ext-price').value,
    Totalintrndr = +document.getElementById('render-int-price').value,
    Totalpp = +document.getElementById('pproduction-price').value,
    TotalPrc = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that in `var TotalPrc = Totalextmdl + Totalintmdl + Totalextrndr + Totalintrndr + Totalpp;` statement, `Totalextmdl`, `Totalintmdl`, `Totalextrndr`, `Totalpp` values are read as string.

You can convert their value into number by putting `+` symbol in front of those variables:

```
var TotalPrc = (+Totalextmdl) + (+Totalintmdl) + (+Totalextrndr) + (+Totalintrndr) + (+Totalpp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `parseInt` or `parseFloat` (depending if you have whole numbers or not)

ex: `parseInt(document.getElementById ('model-ext-price').value)` or `parseFloat(document.getElementById ('model-ext-price').value)`

This ensures you're getting back a number and not a string. Might want to write other logic to do something if parseInt (or parseFloat) fails.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string values to numbers:

```
var allPrc = function () { 
var ids =['model-ext-price','model-int-price',
    'render-ext-price', 'render-int-price', 'pproduction-price'];

var TotalPrice = 0;
ids.forEach(funciton(id) {
        totalPrice+=Number(document.getElementById(id).value;
    });
return TotalPrice;
}

document.getElementById('All-price').value = allPrc;
```